# I want to create a bar graph that counts the number of times a variable occurs in the dataset

Tags: r, graph

I have just started using R and am currently trying to create a bar graph that shows the amount of times each "category" is used. The categories include things like Travel & Events and Sports.
I've tried a few things that come up with errors

```
 barplot(freq, main = category) +geom_bar(stat=category)
Error in as.graphicsAnnot(main) : object 'category' not found
```

```
ggplot(data=dat, aes(category))
Error in ggplot(data = dat, aes(category)) : object 'dat' not found
```

The one time I got a graph to appear it has no data in it just a bunch of lines.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimum reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, I think this is an example of what you are after.  I used the starwars data set, which is accessible through the tidyverse package:

```
# load the tidyverse
library(tidyverse)

# take a look at the starwars data set
starwars

# this will show the numbers in each category of hair_colour, which will be plotted below
starwars %>% count(hair_color)

# plot hair colour using ggplot
ggplot(dat = starwars, aes(x = hair_color)) + 
  geom_bar() + 
  coord_flip()
```

From the documentation for `geom_bar()`:  "geom_bar() makes the height of the bar proportional to the number of cases in each group", which is - I think - what you wanted?

This should work if you substitute `starwars` with your own data, and `hair_colour` for your variable of interest.